# Unable to upload directly from network drive to picasaweb

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, networking, samba, google-picasa

My network drive is bookmarked and clearly visible in nautilus.

One little thing that I do not like in ubuntu is that network drives are not always available from applications. Last time I have noticed this was when I was trying to upload pictures to picasaweb from my home server. When picasaweb opens up nautilus the network drives are not visible anymore.

Typing in the link to the drive in the location field does not work either.

I think the same problem is valid for the photobook program from pixum.

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this limitation by connecting to the network share by mounting it on your system, rather than connecting to it in Nautilus. (It will then still be accessible in Nautilus, as a drive, and it will appear as a drive in other applications too, including other applications that don't display Nautilus's gvfs mounts.)

One way to do this, assuming these are Samba (SMB/CIFS) shares (i.e., Windows or Windows-style shares, including the default way to share folders on an Ubuntu system over a network), is to use `smbmount`. For example, to mount a network share called `foo` on a computer called `192.168.1.100`, logging in to that machine as the user `ek`, you can first create a mount point for it by opening a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

`sudo mkdir /media/foo`

And then, when you want to connect t it, mount the share:

`sudo smbmount //192.168.1.100/foo /media/foo -o user=ek`

When you run commands with `sudo` and you see `[sudo] password for user32762:` (assuming `user32762` is your username on the Ubuntu machine from which you are connecting), you should put in `user32762`'s password for the local machine (i.e., the machine you're connecting from). But after running `sudo smbmount ...`, you'll also (or perhaps only) be asked for a password, and that's `ek`'s password on the remote machine (i.e., the machine you're connecting to).

With the share mounted in this way, you can access its contents from any application (just browse to `/media/foo`).

When you're done using the share, you should unmount it:

`sudo umount /media/foo`

Answer (score 2):

Also, note that if you've accessed a network share already, and it's showing up in your normal nautilus sidebar with a little 'eject' sign next to it, then it will be mounted inside the hidden .gvfs directory in your home folder

```
    /home/user/.gvfs/name_of_mounted_share/
```

You can toggle the show hidden by

```
    ctrl-h
```

In nautilus, or I think the upload window too.